# Change google search location beyond current country

Tags: geolocation, locale, google-search

I often work remotely and prefer using en-us locale settings for my searches. One of our computers is located in Germany, and whenever I try to change the location in Google Search Settings, I get an answer to "Pleas enter a valid Deutschland city or zip code".

I [checked this post](https://superuser.com/questions/172340/location-for-google-search-and-firefox-wrong), but it doesn't apply, as my language settings en-us and the Google search language is also set to English. It clearly uses the IP address of the computer.

I couldn't find an answer in the Google help pages, anyone any idea how to change it London, New-York or Amsterdam?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually just go to:

http://www.google.com/ncr

This works for other countries too, so for example I was able to go to Deutschland Google with:

http://www.google.de/ncr

Just bookmark the appropriate country with the ncr URL and you should be localized to whatever TLD you decide to use.  I think NCR likely means "no country redirect" or similar, though I haven't seen an official word on it anywhere.

Comment: Great! that seems to work. I tried http://google.com (without the suffix path) earlier, but that annoyingly redirected to http://google.de. Great tip!